# Django models relationship confusions between ManytoOne, OneToMany and ManyToMany relationships

Tags: python, django-models

I'm learning Django framework and having troubles with models relationship.
I can't understand where should I use ManytoOne, OneToMany and ManyToMany relationships. And it's getting even worse when I try to imagine it.

For example I have simple Product and each Product should have 1 category

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = models.TextField()
    price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=3, max_digits=20)
    is_available = models.BooleanField()
    category = models.ForeignKey('Category', on_delete=models.PROTECT)

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return f'Product: {self.name}'


class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return f"Category: {self.name}"
```

Here many product can have only 1 category and 1 category can have many products
But If 1 product can have multiple categories. For example:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = models.TextField()
    price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=3, max_digits=20)
    is_available = models.BooleanField()

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return f'Product - {self.name}'


class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.PROTECT)

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return f"Category - {self.name}"
```

Here 1 product can have many categories but 1 category should have only 1 product. But if I try to add more than 1 product to 1 category it still works.

So should I use ManytoMany relationship here? I think it's the best way here but I heard than ManyToMany are too messy and I should always avoid them if it's possible.
Or I can just add unique together? (I don't think it's a good idea)
I can't understand why am I even able to add more than 1 product to the same category if it's OnetoMany relationship.

Comment: I think in this instance a join table between the two with a unique constraint is probably the best way to represent this. I forget the syntax for that in django atm, but I'm not sure how else you would want to model it. Assuming you want "Category" to represent specific things and not just "Hardware" or "Electronics". Basically if you want many small categories, probably join table. If the categories are broad, having one model or the other own it and having to look through isn't necessarily bad.

Comment: @therealdakotal Specifically for this instance I consider to have categories like "Hardware" or "Electronics". So I think the best way for it will be ManyToMany relationship. But also I can't understand is it right to add a unique_together

Comment: Yes because if you don't have that constraint your table could end up duplicating data. Without unique constraints

Cat A <-> Prod X (already exists)
You run an insert stmt saying "Create Cat A <-> Prod X". Now when you 
"give me all categories for Prod X", there will be two (or more) `Cat A` records

Comment: thanks now It more clear